# Calculating time-varying velocity and final speed through second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

I have to work through an example from physics to strengthen my understanding of Newton's second law of motion through second-order ODEs.

I've been provided with the following settings: that the skydiver is descending under a parachute at a steady rate, where t is the time; and I have to assume zero displacement and velocity at time zero.

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + \frac{k}m^{}\frac{dy}{dt} = g$$

I've come to the following general solution y(t):

$$y(t) = A + Be^{-\frac{kt}{m}} + g\frac{m}{k}t$$

If I set the displacement and velocity at time zero, I got:

$$A=-B=-g\frac{m^2}{k^2}$$

From that point, how can I calculate:

1. Time-varying vertical velocity?
2. Final speed corresponding to the speed of the skydiver when descending at a steady rate?

Comment: what do you mean by time-varying vertical velocity? Do you just mean the velocity as a function of time? If yes, then just compute $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ because that's the definition of velocity. For question two, once you find an expression for the velocity, you should compute $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{dy}{dt}$

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I somehow can't understand how I can evaluate this equation to find the first derivative.

Comment: you've already done the difficult part of solving the ODE to find $y(t)$. Calculating $\frac{dy}{dt}$ should be the easy part; you just apply the standard rules of differentiation, like the sum rule, the chain rule, the rule for differentiating exponentials, the rule for differentiating polynomials etc. The final answer should be $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = -B \dfrac{k}{m} e^{-kt/m} + g \dfrac{m}{k}$. (BTW, you have an $x$ in the exponent, which I'm pretty sure should be a $t$ instead)

Comment: why haven't you just set the g(m/k) to zero if we treat it as a constant? There is no value t there.

Comment: There's a $t$ in the last term of $y(t)$, so $\dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{mg}{k} t\right) = \dfrac{mg}{k}$

Comment: Omg yes, I see. And how can I find the final speed at a steady rate?

Comment: for the expression of $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ above, take the limit as $t \to \infty$. To understand how this works, I suggest that for simplicity, you set $m=g=k = 1$, then use a graphing calculator, like Desmos or Wolfram Alpha to plot it. After doing it in this pecial case, try to see what the answer is in the genral case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical velocity is given by

$$V=\frac{dy}{dt}=...$$

and the final velocity is

$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{dy}{dt}=g\frac mk$$
The exponential term goes to zero.

Comment: How did you come up with the final velocity? Isn't that we should calculate the acceleration (which is the second derivative) and set it to zero?

Comment: No, the final speed is the limit when $t$ becomes great.

Comment: Why didn't you include the first beat from the first derivative then?

Comment: @MariaLavrovskaya which first beat. you  mean the exponential. it goes to zero.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point where I am confused. Why does it go to zero?

Comment: For example when $t$ goes to infinity $e^{-t}$ goes to zero.

Comment: So it tends to very small number and that's why it equals zero?

Comment: When $t$ goes to infinity $e^t$ goes to infinity and its inverse $\frac{1}{e^t}=e^{-t}$ will go to $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$.